# Observing factory variable from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-factory, angularjs-digest

**Simplified code:**

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.factory("mySrvc", function($window) {
  var win = angular.element($window);
  var foo = {
    bar: 0
  };
  
  win.bind("click", function(){
    foo.bar = foo.bar + 1;
    alert("triggered! foo.bar="+foo.bar);
  });
    
  return {
    foo: foo,
    update: function() {
      foo.bar = foo.bar + 1
    }
  };
});

myApp.controller("myCtrl", function(mySrvc) {
  this.foo = mySrvc.foo;
  mySrvc.update();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl as ctrl">
      {{ctrl.foo.bar}}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now when I run the app, the update trigger in the controller updates `foo.bar` successfully to 1 and the observer from the {{}} model updates the html accordingly. But it updates in the factory itself by clicking the mouse, which does the exact same thing as the update function, the change doesn't appear in the HTML.
 Any tries with an additional scope in the controller were unsuccessful.
Why is that and how do I observe the change?

Comment: `.bind("click", ...` doesn't cause a digest cycle - you'd need wrap it in `$rootScope.$apply(function(){...})`

Comment: @PankajParkar, yes... but, in this case, he is dealing with a global `$window`, so it might just be OK. I mean, how else would you do it? And actually, is `window` technically considered DOM? :)

Comment: @NewDev sorry for my previous comment dude..but just currious to know why it should be in service not in directive..

Comment: @PankajParkar This is not my actual code but just a sample to reproduce the problem in a simple way. My actual app is rendering (60fps) and calling a function in a factory (here `mySrvc`) for each render to update an object (here `foo`), which my controller (here `myCtrl`) observes. And the issue is the same as reproduced here: If the function is called externally, it updates the interface variable, but not if the periodic event triggers it. So it seems I have to manually apply the change. Although running digest 60 times per second might not be smart...

Comment: @PankajParkar, why wouldn't it? Here's your forked plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/5l4WU12WlZ07FdivGZn6?p=preview. It might not be ideal (i.e. $digest could be in progress), but it does work

Comment: @NewDev yes you are correct I added an answer..based on your comment only.Thanks :)\

Comment: @PankajParkar, as to why not a directive - directive attaches to a DOM element. Which DOM element would you use here? Maybe `<body>`. But, still, if you'd also want to observe it elsewhere, how would you tie it a directive in a way that does rely on peculiarities of a scope inheritance?

Comment: @NewDev Yes I see your point there...sorry I'm still learning..Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @NewDev suggested you could use `$rootScope.$apply` or just you could do it indirectly by adding `$timeout` which will fire digest cycle for you.

**Code**

```
win.bind("click", function() {
    $timeout(function() {
       foo.bar = foo.bar + 1;
       alert("triggered! foo.bar=" + foo.bar);
    });
});
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/pBNUTG?p=preview)

Comment: It seems to do the job. Can you say anything about the performance? Is it fine to call $timeout basically 60 times a second?

Comment: @Miiller yes, you have to..if you want to update binding of scope variables..I won't affect performance if its only one in number..